# how to change my md5 to a hashed password in php

Tags: php

My teacher wants to change my md5 password that was already made to a hashed one. I tried to use hashed but I cant login. I'm new with coding and I'm really confused on why I can't login.

This is my Sign Up page:

```php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnCreate'])){
    $Aboutme = "This portion is about what can baby sitter tell about themselves to attract Parents/Guardian.";
    $txtName = trim($_POST['txtName']);
    $cboType = trim($_POST['cboType']);
    $txtUser = trim($_POST['txtUser']);
    $pwPass = $_POST['pwPass'];
    $pass = password_hash($pwPass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $exist = DB::query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE u_username=?",array($txtUser),"READ");

    if (count($exist)>0){
        error('Username already exist!');
    } else {

        if($cboType == "Sitter"){
            DB::query("INSERT INTO user(u_type, u_name, u_aboutme, u_username, u_password, u_hires) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)",array($cboType, $txtName, $Aboutme, $txtUser, $pass,0),"CREATE");
        }
        else {
            DB::query("INSERT INTO user(u_type, u_name, u_username, u_password, u_hires) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)",array($cboType, $txtName, $txtUser, $pass,0),"CREATE");
        }

        $exist_id = DB::query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE u_username=?",array($txtUser),"READ");

        if (count($exist_id)>0){
            $exist_id = $exist_id[0];

            DB::query("INSERT INTO subs(u_id) VALUES(?)",array($exist_id['u_id']),"CREATE");
        }

        success('Successfully created an account!');
```

This is my login page:

```php
$txtUser = "";
$pwPass = "";
loginUser('btnLogin', 'txtUser', 'pwPass');
?>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtUser" required>

        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="pwPass" required>
        <button type="submit" name="btnLogin">Log In</button>
        <a href="create.php">Create</a>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="a-div">
    <a href="forgotpass.php">Forgot Password?</a>
</div>
```

Comment: try and hash the password online https://phppasswordhash.com/ , compare it to the hash on your db and see if there is a deffirence they may help to identify the source of mismatch

Comment: Do you need to change the current md5 hash to another hash method without having your users have to create a new password? Or do you just need to update your md5 hashing method to a better one, and don't care about the current passwords?

Comment: You haven't posted any of the code that actually handles the login.

Comment: @Leroy The instructions were just to change md5 to hash. I can just delete the current users

Comment: Then you need to share your code where you fetch the user and verify the password. 
Also `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` uses bcrypt at this moment, but the docs state: `Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP`. So relying on a constant that could be changed over time is not good. 

Share the code that has some `md5` code in it, since that's your previous password validation.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot login with the old password since it uses different hashing algorithme and it is impossible to decrypt , you can only compare it against a plain text password .

there are two things to bare in mind :

- You need to trim passwords too  `$pwPass = trim($_POST['pwPass']);`
- you should use `password_verify($password , $hashedpassword);`  in
  your loginUser .

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Yes, that is the one that I'm confused about. I don't know where to put password_verify. I can register but I can't log in to the newly created account. Again I'm sorry I'm really new and I don't have a knack for logic :c

Comment: password_verify() goes into your loginUser.php , 

first get $_POST variable from your login page 
select the user from db
password_verify the password with the hash
if it passes redirect 

i advise you to read this https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php